# How to dynamically generate X amount of new <input> based on the value of a <select> (within Angular2)?

Tags: javascript, web, angular

I'll try to make this as simple as possible.

**Problem:**

I've got a page where I need to have X amount of `<input>` tags generated depending on the value chosen in a `<select>`.

**Stack/Tech:** Angular2/Javascript

**Example:**

The dropdown asks, "How many kids do you have?"

If the user selects 3 in the `<select>` dropdown, then 3 total `<input>` fields are generated and inserted in the `<div>` right after the question.

**What I've Tried:**

I've successfully pulled it off already but it's semi-unreliable and I don't feel like this is the "proper" way to do things.

***Failure 1:***

I tried using `*ngFor` with conventional `for` loop logic. I just did something like this:

`for(let i = 0; i < selectValue; i++)`

It didn't like that. Apparently `*ngFor` is mostly used to iterate through arrays and objects and can't be used with conventional `for` logic.

***Failure 2:***

I tried to pre-generate an array of objects, a multidimensional array, and a JSON-style object with empty but pre-filled fields.

My goal was to generate X objects in an array where X corresponds to the `select` number that the user chose. Then the `*ngFor` could iterate through this "pre-filled" array, display the inputs, and then I would fill that object later to be sent over HTTP.

Basically when the `<select>` changes it would call a function while passing the number the user chose. That function would generate a new array with X amount of objects.

No idea why this didn't work.

***Success (but isn't ideal):***

I tried binding `[innerHTML] = generatedHTML` and then filled the generatedHTML variable with traditional Javascript. This made `<input>` that seemed to worked fine, but this seems like a HORRIBLE way to do this. Plus I need to create event binders on each of these new `<input>` and I'm not sure if manually inserted [innerHTML] will work properly within Angular2's zones if I insert it in such a terrible fashion.

***Bonus Question***

After getting the inputs added I'd like to access their values in the easiest and most complete way possible. Is it possible to add multiple data inputs to ONE ngModel and then access each individual input through iteration? Or do I need to figure out another way to do this? Could I just put all those inputs under one `<form>` and then tie that `<form>` to a single data model?

Thanks for the help everyone! Pretty new to Angular 2 but digging it a lot so far :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

1. Assign a ng-change function to your select
2. Process the ng-model bound value of the select in that function (to create a new Array with n-Elements)
3. Add whatever info to each inputArray element you need later to decorate the input boxes
4. Do a ng-repeat over that array to create your input's

HTML:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="number" (ngModelChange)="nrChanged()">
  <option *ngFor="let nr of numbers" [value]="nr">{{nr}}</option>
</select>
<input *ngFor="let inputInfo of inputArr" type="text" placeholder="text" />
```

Component:

```
private numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
private number;
private inputArr = [];

 nrChanged()
 {
  this.inputArr = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < this.number; i++){

      /*here you can assign any information you need for creating the concrete input */
      this.inputArr[i] = {neededInfo: 'I am the ' + i + 'Element'};
  }
```

Comment: this is angular2 question and your answer is for angular 1

Comment: You're right :-O My bad, the concept should be same. Somebody rewrites to angular2, otherwise I remove it..

Comment: I'll give this a shot right now (in angular2). I found another solution which I don't like... this might be the best one. Thanks so much for your help! :)

Comment: Cool, let me know if it works. If so, just edit my code to make it angular2

Comment: Worked perfectly! A very neat and clean solution for my problem, thanks! (gonna edit your post now)